# Plotting phase dates

Tags: r, graph, plot

I am having troubles trying to figure out how one would create a line graph with individual plants on the Y axis and on the X axis a continuous line segmented into the plants respective opening, sex phase, and wilt dates.

I have roughly 60 individual plants - each with anywhere from 5-15 flowers - and their respective opening dates, the date they entered male phase, the date they entered female phase, and the subsequent wilting date for the individual flowers.

Here is the data I have so far: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7lhz8z0qo4sla5w/Dphase.txt?dl=0

Here is a crude drawing of the graph I'm trying to create (the values I graphed are arbitrary): https://www.dropbox.com/s/8qd1ela0093dvoq/2015-10-15%2013.29.55.jpg?dl=0

PID = name of the plant

Gender= (m/f -> male/female) the gender of the plant when measurements were taken (Note that opening is included in the Gender row m, although it didn't enter male phase until the date specified under 'sex'. Similarly in the f row, the date specifies under 'sex' corresponds to when it left male phase and entered female phase)

Opening = the date when a plants flower opened

Sex = the date when the flower entered its respective sex phase Wilt = the date the individual flower wilted

Flower = the relative flower position within the plant

Hopefully my links have worked. If anyone could give me a hand in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far? That way we can help you mould your code rather than write it outright.

Comment: Do you have the full date with year? Charting time series is more complex without complete dates (including year).

Comment: Actually it doesn't have an answer, and the reason it doesn't is that you have not provided the expected sample data.

Comment: @BondedDust sorry, this is my first time posting here and there is clearly something I am unaware of. Are you unable to click my link to dropbox where my data is provided?